# Why is my sticky bar unstable?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am learning how to make a sticky bar using CSS and jQuery.

The code is a little bit dirty, beacuse in order to make the sticky bar work, I need a long page.
You can see the code [here](http://pastebin.com/82eJtzYx).

To replay the issue, you need to do what I say.

1) Open the page in the newest Firefox or Chrome.

2) Drag the scrollbar of your browser directly to the end of the page(Don't stop in the middle). You will see the sticky bar slide down, then slide up, finally slide down.

3) Drag the scrollbar whatever you want, and issue just disappears.

4) Then refresh the page, do the same thing in step 2, you will see the issue again

That's really not the sticky bar I want. I don't want the thing in step 2 appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_slidedown.asp), instead of giving the sticky_bar element `visibility: hidden;`, you have to make it `display: none;`.

> Note: slideDown() works on elements hidden with jQuery methods and display:none in CSS (but not visibility:hidden).

You can see the full edited code [***here***](http://pastebin.com/e70ctVGy) or run it below to see the difference in behavior.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
        $(window).scroll(function()
        {
                if($(window).scrollTop() >= 60)
                {
                        $(".sticky_bar").slideDown("slow")
                        $(".sticky_bar").addClass("sticky_bar_active");
                }
                else
                {
                        $(".sticky_bar").slideUp("slow");
                        $(".sticky_nav").removeClass("sticky_bar_active");
                }
        });

});
```

```css
.sticky_bar p {
        display: inline;
        font-size: 13px;
        padding-right: 6px;
}

.sticky_bar a {
        text-decoration: none;
        float: left;
}

.sticky_bar {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;  
        width: 100%;  
        height: 65px;
        left: 0;  
        top: 0;  
        z-index: 100;  
        border-top: 0;

        margin: 0;
        border: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #000000;
}

.sticky_bar_active {
        position: fixed;  
        width: 100%;  
        height: 65px;
        left: 0;  
        top: 0;  
        z-index: 100;  
        border-top: 0;  
}

.sticky_text {
        color: #FFFFFF;
}

.wrapper {
        width: 1170px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        </head>
<body>
        <nav class='sticky_bar'>
                <ul class='wrapper'>
                        <li>
                                <a href='#'><div class='sticky_text'><p>Overview</p></div></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                                <a href='#'><div class='sticky_text'><p>Details</p></div></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                                <a href='#'><div class='sticky_text'><p>Settings</p></div></a>
                        </li>
                </ul>
        </nav>
        <ul>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
        </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I really appreciate for your help.